# get SensorValues from Arduino ADK

Tags: android

I'am working with arduino and ADK und I have problems to get Information from Arduino-Sensors. At the moment I can send Information from Phone to control LED or servos.... . But it is impossible for me to send Data via acc.write(msg,3) to smarthphone. I'am using this example [Dev-O-Rama](http://marioboehmer.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-adk-with-standard-arduino-uno.html) and try to extend this example to get sensor data(without success). To get sensordata I'am using code from ADK example. Everytime when I try to send data from arduino with: acc.write(msg,3) it seems everything freezing. Have someone a working "little" example or a hint what can cause this behavior?

LG Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it's the Android application that's freezing?

Try using the [USBControl](http://code.google.com/p/mover-bot/source/browse/trunk/Android-1.0/src/com/agentx3r/lib/USBControl.java) library in my [project](http://code.google.com/p/mover-bot/)

The arduino write code is very simple:

```
    //Batt update, 0.1 Hz loop
    if (acc.isConnected() && millis()-timer_batt >= 1000/BATT_FREQ) {
            timer_batt = millis();
            //Serial.print("b");
            msg[0] = SYNC;
            msg[1] = BATTERY_LEVEL;
            msg[2] = getBatt();
            acc.write(msg, 3);

    }
```

Make sure you're limiting the writing frequency, and reading quickly enough on both sides. There's a strange behaviour where the connection will appear to hang if there's too much data being buffered.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what to do without knowing what kind of data you are sending. Basically you have to make sure use the `acc.write()` method with the correct parameters. The first one is the byte array itself and the second one is the number of bytes in the array. So if your byte array is **5** bytes in size you need to call it like that: `acc.write(msg, 5)`.

It is even better to make it more dynamic by using the sizeof Arduino function:

```
acc.write(msg, sizeof(msg));
```